# How to similate gesture event in mobile device programmatically on AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, mobile, air

I try to simulate the swipe gesture event on a real device, but nothing happens.

```
myList.dispatchEvent(new TransformGestureEvent(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, true, false, 'all', 56, 112, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, false, false, false, false, false));
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  What component are you trying to simulate the event on?  If a List [or list based class[, I suspect you have to dispatch the event on a child of the List not on the actual list.

Comment: I asked the question yesterday - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897035/flex-spinnerlist-how-animate-spin. I was able to make an animation (in the answer), but it is not natural, not smooth. As the result I was not satisfied, I began looking for other options. To be honest I did not want to animate a List, but a SpinnerList. I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why would anything happen?

1. Flex components DO NOT rely on those built-in gestures.
2. Even if they would — scrolling would be done on pan(drag) rather than discrete swipe.

Comment: Well. thank you. But how I can progromatically emulate to scrolling SpinnerLis?

Comment: The animation is not smooth, an items simply replace each other,  without inertia.

Comment: Yes, I used easing - no effect.